# Stopping SqlDependency exceedingly slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sqldependency

I call in my C# the following to stop the SqlDependency.

```
rslt = SqlDependency.Stop(myConnStr, _notificationQueue);
```

This takes about 4-5 seconds.  I've put up the SQL Profiler to see what is happening and it calls the following (in a single batch) and that takes 4-5 seconds:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
        DROP SERVICE [SqlQueryNotificationService-45558b70-3adc-414b-9f7b-1da40abfc5b6]; 
        DROP QUEUE [SqlQueryNotificationService-45558b70-3adc-414b-9f7b-1da40abfc5b6]; 
        DROP PROCEDURE [SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-45558b70-3adc-414b-9f7b-1da40abfc5b6]; 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;',
        N'@p2 int', @p2 = 60000
```

Why is it so slow and how do I speed it up?

Comment: Run sp_whoisactive while that is being executed. Most likely, it's blocking because there are readers finishing. Actually, why are you stopping the dependency?

Comment: @usr I am stopping it because I am quitting the app.